# How to replace each elements in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Here is the code:

```
x = as.matrix(data.frame(replicate(10,rnorm(1000))))
y = as.matrix(data.frame(replicate(10,rnorm(800))))

output <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(x[,1]), nrow = length(y[,1])))

for (i in range(length(x[,1]))) {
  for(j in range(length(y[,1]))){
    output[i,j] = cor.test(x[i,],y[j,],method = c("pearson"))$p.value
  }
}
```

I want to find the correlation p-value for each row of x and each row of y. But I don't know why the p-values did not store in the empty data frame output...

Comment: What is your purpose? Finding correlations' p.value at row base? or column base? By the way, why the matrices are unequal? (1000 vs 800)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing R between python

Here is the correct code:

```
for (i in 1:length(x[,1])) {
  for(j in 1:length(y[,1])){
    output[i,j] = cor.test(x[i,],y[j,],method = c("pearson"))$p.value
  }
}
```